# Positioning tooltip in the kendo chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart, kendo-tooltip

Is there way to position `tooltip` in `kendo chart` apart from modifying CSS for class *`k-chart-tooltip`*?

I want the `tooltip` to be positioned at the top using the `kendo chart` attributes.
Here is the image on how it should look:

### [**Image**](http://i60.tinypic.com/foq552.png)

Answer (score -1):

If you change the .k-chart-tooltip style, then it will be applied to all tooltips used in the application.

Applying tooltip style only on chart control could be possible, if we can bring the kendo chart tooltip inside the chart control instead of  tag (latest kendo version feature).

Then we can easily apply the tooltip CSS style only on kendochart.

I do not have any idea how could we bring kendo tooltip inside chart control.